# Android Touch Click vs Programatic Click

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have been struggling with getting a Listview Selected Item to change Background Color and have now zeroed in on the actual source of the problem - so now I need assistance in resolving it.

I have a Listview where Selected Items may be chosen by either a physical Touch or by Voice Recognition.

I also have the following code which executes when either selection method is used

```
listLocations.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      Object pickedItem = listLocations.getItemAtPosition(position);
      view.setSelected(true);
      view.setPressed(true);
      }
  });
```

Additionally I have a Selector configured into the Listview so as to change the Selected Item Background Color based on the Selected Item's State

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@color/orange_500" />
     <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/blue_500" />
     <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/green_500" />
     <item android:state_active="false" android:drawable="@color/red_600" />
     <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/purple_500" />
     <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

This works just fine when a physical Touch is used on the Listview GUI to make the Item selection.

But when the Voice Recognition is used the onItemClick() code executes fine, but it appears as though the Item State is not really changed - because the Selector is never changing the selected Item's Background Color.

How can I resolve this so that I get the Selected Item's State to change when either a physical Touch is used or Voice Recognition?

Thanks

Comment: How do you click programmatically?

Comment: I use the function:  MyList.performItemClick()  and I include the various parameters defining: MyList and the selected ListViewID

Comment: Did you called       view.setSelected(true);
      view.setPressed(true); on the views you want to focus trough Voice?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes - when the Voice Recognition returns its value, I interrogate the data source to find where within the Listiview that item exists (which Listview ID).  I then, using that "matchingLotID", 1. Select that Listview Item with:  parkingSpaceList.setSelection(matchingLotID);  **parkingSpaceList.refreshDrawableState();**  and 'Press" the item with   **parkingSpaceList.setPressed(true);**   **parkingSpaceList.refreshDrawableState();**  and finally launch the **MyList.performItemClick()** method which again sets the **setPressed()**

Comment: After all of that the Selected Item Background Color is supposed to change to reflect its current State.   And this works fine for a physical Touch, but no change is seen on a Programmatic 'Touch' like this.